# Validation for decimal value does not prevent entering an arbitrary string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin, simple-form

I have a validation for my `price` property of my class `Product`:

```
validates_numericality_of :price, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.5, allow_blank: true
```

So when I enter a value that is too small, I get a validation message:

[image: Validation works]

However, when I enter a garbage value like a string `abcdefg` the model saves, but sets the price back to `nil`.

This is a critical bug, since the user might enter `100 $` and that data will be lost, without the user noticing.

From my `schema.rb`s

```
t.decimal  "price", precision: 10, scale: 2
```

How can I make sure, that the user can't add such an invalid value?

Comment: The model is saving since you have `allow_blank: true`.

Comment: @max: This sounds plausible but `abcdefg` is not a valid value so it should not save IMHO, also 0.01 is another non-valid value and there the validation works.

Comment: the way it works is that it converts to a number eg using to_f... `"abcdef".to_f` returns `nil` .Question: have you tried entering `100 $` to see what actually happens?

Comment: Yeah, but the way the validator works is that it uses `Kernel.Float` to convert the raw value. If it does not return a float the value is set to nil. And if you have `allow_blank: true` it short circuits so that is is valid. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f888fad4db6d6956b675ca0441baa5aa63edae32/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb

Comment: It does not add a separate error to the errors hash as you might expect if the value is set but not a decimal / number at all. If you need this exact behavior you might want to create your own validator.

Comment: In addition you could try to `validates_format_of :price, with: /[0-9.]*/`.